# How to make object move farther longer you hold down?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a program where the longer you hold down the screen the higher an object will move. I want to do it where the longer you hold down the longer the function repeats increasing the distance. However, for some reason it is not working.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

var calculateTimer = Timer()

var distance = 10
var choice = 1

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var planet = SKNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) { // viewdidload

    let planetTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "mercury.jpg")

    planet = SKSpriteNode(texture: planetTexture)
    planet.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    addChild(planet)

}

func calculateDistance() {

    distance += 10

    print(distance)
    print(choice)

}

func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    calculateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.calculateDistance), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    print("test")

}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    planet.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true

    //planet.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))

    planet.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: distance))

}



override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}

}
```

This is my code. If anyone has any suggestions they would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should mention what exactly is happening instead of saying "not working". What do you see on the screen?

Comment: @adev The image will show but when I click nothing happens and nothing prints

Answer (score 0):

In touchDown, set a flag to indicate a touch has started.
In touchUp, clear/remove the flag.

Whilst the flag is set, keep performing your movement code.